# Cell swipe event and button touch inside event

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer

I have a table cell view with 4 UIButtons:

[image]

Buttons have Touch Up Inside event

```
@IBAction func increasDealRatingAction(sender:UIButton) {
    let buttonPosition = sender.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView: self.tableView)
    if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(buttonPosition) {
       ...
    }
}
```

And i have edit actions for each cell:

[image]

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    ...
    return [addToWishListAction, addToPurchasesAction, deleteAction]
}
```

The issue, when you swipe left to show “add to wish list”, ”delete” actions from position of star buttons, click event handled too or swipe action doesn't detect while you swipe on button area.

Comment: if you are using UISwipeGestureRecognizer then please use default tableviewSwipe or you can use third party library to show swipe button (like SWTableViewCell).

Answer (score 0):

Add a swipe gesture recognizer to the buttons

```
let swipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("handleSwipes:")) // nil for selector is also possible
swipeGestureRecognizer.direction = .Left // Add this if you want only one direction
dealRatingButton.addGestureRecognizer(swipeGestureRecognizer)
// Add three star buttons
```

and impletment `gestureRecognizer(_:shouldReceiveTouch:)` to return `false`.

Comment: I added your code, but don't understand what is this ```gestureRecognizer(_:shouldReceiveTouch:)``` ?  and what should be in handleSwipes function ?

Comment: It's a method within `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`. If you want to do nothing, just set nil rather than selector, as I wrote in the comment

Comment: The correct usage of this will definitely solve at least your second problem 'swipe action doesn't detect while you swipe on button area.'. Post what you tried or nothing can be solved.

Comment: So i add delegate method:

```func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceiveTouch touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
return false;
}```

And add your code for button.

Comment: Then when i starting swipe inside button, cell ignore swipe and edit buttons not showing. And at the end button click event triggered. I need a invisible layer under all buttons, that will open edit actions when i swipe...

Comment: Send the swipe recognizer to cell to handle. Use `TapGestureRecognizer` rather than listen to `touchInsideUp` for your buttons. Don't worry if you want to add extra layers.